# android Passing touch events of a Child view drawn outside of view clip bounds (ViewPager Page 1 to Page 2)

Tags: android, android-viewpager

My Android ViewPager has set to draw views outside of the bounds (Clip bounds set to false) . I have a touch event listener on all the views displayed on the page. The custom view is displayed on the page 1, drawn outside of its clipping Bounds and overflows to the page 2. The touch event on the page 1 works fine. When scrolled to the second page, the remaining view is displayed. The issue is that the touch event on the custom view (added on the page 1) does not get called when clicked on the Page 2.

**PageViewActivity.cs**

```
ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setClipChildren(false);
mViewPager.setClipToPadding(false);
```

**PageViewFragment.cs**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_layout, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    View view1=(View)v.findViewById(R.id.view1);
    view1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "View clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
        }
    });return v;
```

}

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:clipChildren="false" 
android:clipToPadding="false" >
<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="#ff0000" />
```

**Fragment Layout - page_layout.xml**

Any suggestions?

Comment: Show the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: @PM77-1 added code. @+id/view1 is displayed on the page 1 and page2. click event is working on the page 1, not on the page2.

Answer (score 0):

There’s a problem here. We can swipe only the middle view. This is because the touch events occur outside the ViewPagers bounds. We can override the onTouchEvent of the ViewPagerContainer and dispatch the events to the ViewPager to solve this.

```
private ViewPager mPager;

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    mPager = (ViewPager) getChildAt(0);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return mPager.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

But the truth is you're better off using the more modern solutions to this stuff.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/result_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/grey"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/medium_grey" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

So tabbed layout and a properly setup viewpager. Though even this is going to be kind of obsolete once Google finishes up their Navigation bit in their Architecture Components.

Comment: Okay, removed it. Most all of this answer is garbage now. Mostly you can modernly properly have viewpagers that fill the screen and capture the touch events without having to delegate them in from the parent container, but suffice it to say the reason the above didn't worked is because it didn't get the touch events because it wasn't touched because it's size and position were not where that touch event occurred.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually detect the touch events, and see if it's coordinates lie within the bounds of the pages outside the bounds.  So going off of what Tatarize states, before dispatching touch events to the pager, you should check if the event is within one of the pages of the view pager.

Here is example code, I'm only checking if the x lies within the bounds and not the y in childContains().

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                return pager.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                int childCount = pager.getChildCount();
                int x = (int) event.getX();
                int y = (int) event.getY();
                for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                    final View child = pager.getChildAt(i);
                    if (childContains(child, x)) {
                        // delay the click minimally in-case
                        // callOnClick performs mods on the pager
                        // 
                        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                child.callOnClick();
                            }
                        }, 100);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                break;
        }

        return pager.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }

int[] loc = new int[2];
private boolean childContains(View child, final int x) {
        child.getLocationOnScreen(loc);
        int x1_child = loc[0];
        int x2_child = x1_child + child.getWidth();
        int x0 = x;
        boolean isInside = x0 >= x1_child && x0 < x2_child;

        Log.v("childContains()", String.format("x: %s x1_child: %s x2_child: %s isInside: %s",
                x0, x1_child, x2_child, String.valueOf(isInside)));
        return isInside;
    }
```